# Parse Error on input 'sum' in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm writing a short program in haskell to find the mean of the list of odd numbers between 1 and 2000 that are not divisible by 3 or 5. I can't get it to compile and keep getting a variety of errors. I made some changes and now the code is giving me a "Parse error on input 'sum'" on line 5 col 9. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
--Write a Haskell function that calculates the mean of a list of odd numbers that
--are not divisible by 3 or 5 and whose sum is less than 2000.
mean :: Int
mean = let nums = [x|x <- [1,3..1999], x 'mod' 3 != 0, x 'mod' 5 != 0]
    sum nums/length nums
```

I'm compiling with GHCI.
Thanks

Comment: Is this homework, and is the comment in the code the original task description? If so, I'd say you have misunderstood it.

Comment: Yes the comment at the top is the original question. It's from a past exam paper that I was working through to study for an exam. Why do you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the missing `in` as mentioned by DiegoNolan there are some other minor problems with your definition. First, to use a two-ary function infix, you have to enclose it in backticks ` while you use ticks '. Furthermore, Haskell uses `/=` for inequality and not `!=`. Finally, you cannot use `/` for integer division but function `div`.

```
mean = let nums = [x|x <- [1,3..1999], x `mod` 3 /= 0, x `mod` 5 /= 0]
       in
       sum nums `div` length nums
```

Comment: you have a typo, `numbs` should be `nums`

Comment: Actually, I'd consider it an error if a function to compute the mean silently truncated the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I realised I had those errors too after I added the "in".

Answer (score 2):

you need `in`

```
mean :: Int
mean = let nums = [x|x <- [1,3..1999], x 'mod' 3 != 0, x 'mod' 5 != 0]
       in sum nums/length nums
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I had to fix a few other things too. I was using the wrong quotes for mod and the not equals operator is /= instead != and I had to change the / symbol on the last line to `div`. It works fine now

Comment: @user1786327 You might want to use `fromIntegral` to convert to a rational or floating point type.  A mean of integers isn't really an integer.